# German Blue Card - working for a project in Sweden

Tags: working-visas, germany, eu, sweden, blue-card

I have a German Blue Card since 1.4.2015 for company ABC.
I just received a project in Sweden under ABC's contract for company XYZ (as the client of my company).

Do I need to apply for a working visa in Sweden?

Many thanks
Best Regards
Linh

Comment: What's your nationality? How long are expected to stay in Sweden?

Comment: I'm Vietnamese. The project is first 3 months (so I'll be in Sweden 4 days/week). Then it could be extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to stay and work in Germany for atleast 18 months after the date you received your Blue Card before you can live and work in any other EU country. You won't need a visa as long as the Blue Card is still valid. But you won't be able to stay in any other EU country until 1.10.2016.